# swift, How to use UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have write the following code:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: CatagoryCollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeCardCell",bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HomeCardCell")
    }

}

class CatagoryCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCardCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCardCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

}
```

and I have this error in the log:

> 2018-08-13 12:14:07.706452+0900 xxxxx[6804:3378858]
>   -[ID301Project.HomeViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1065092b0 2018-08-13 12:14:07.707910+0900
>   xxxxx[6804:3378858] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[xxxxx.HomeViewController
>   collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1065092b0'

[image: collectionView]

I want to extend UICollectionView to class.
Can not you expand it like this?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: You didn't mention the error thou

Comment: i guess you forgot to write collectionview.delegate = self and collectionview.datasource = self in viewdidload

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen that will not produce error that just display empty collection i think.

Comment: so can you explain the error you are facing. i didnt find anything error over above code.

Comment: Do you have an .xib file named "HomeCardCell" ?

Comment: -[xxxxxx.HomeViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1065092b0
2018-08-13 12:14:07.707910+0900 xxxxxx[6804:3378858] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[xxxxx.HomeViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1065092b0'    An error occurs.
delegate connected.

Comment: I want to what is bundle.main . in bundle try nil

Answer (score -1):

Add your CellReuseIdentifier string to collection cell(Blue rectangle). Refer below image

[image]